# Mean Value Theorem involving second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ such that $f'(x)>0,f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, then $$\int_a^b e^{f(x)}\,dx\le (b-a)\frac{e^{f(b)}-e^{f(a)}}{f(b)-f(a)}$$

My progress so far:

We have $\frac{1}{b-a} \int\limits_{a}^{b} e^{f(x)} =e^{f(\epsilon)}$ for some $\epsilon \in (a,b)$.

Also, take the function $e^x$ int the RHS, and apply Lagrange MVT to get $e^c$ for some $c \in (f(a),f(b))$ SO, we are left to show that $e^{f(\epsilon)} \le e^c$ or $f(\epsilon) \le c$. I am stuck here. I don't know how to use the fact that $f''(x)>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $[a,b]=[0,1]$ without loss of generality, $f''\geq0$ means $f$ is convex, and thus
$$
f(x)\leq (1-x)f(0)+xf(1),
$$
or,
$$
e^{f(x)}\leq e^{f(0)}e^{x(f(1)-f(0))}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_0^1e^{f(x)}\leq e^{f(0)}\int_0^1e^{x(f(1)-f(0))}=\frac{e^{f(1)}-e^{f(0)}}{f(1)-f(0)}.
$$
(Actually $f'>0$ is only used for the denominator to be nonzero)

Comment: "Assuming $[a,b]=[0,1]$ without loss of generality" I believe you are only proving a specific case, and a great deal of "generality" is being lost this way..

Comment: No. You can see it by a simple linear transformation: if an $f$ is given on $[a,b]$, then consider the function $\hat f(x)=f((b-a)x+a)$, defined on $[0,1]$, use the result for $\hat f$, and the fact that $\int_0^1\hat f=\tfrac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf$

Comment: Simple and beautiful as it should be +1

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake: there is no loss of generality here. If you are the downvoter consider to undo it.